# Child routes not refreshing without hash in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am working on an angular project. Earlier I was using hash location strategy but I came to know its not good for SEO.

So I tried to remove it.

Now some of my children routes don't open and some don't refresh.

Here is a look to my **app.module.ts**:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent },
      { path: 'student-dashboard', component: StudentDashboardComponent },
      { path: 'tutor-dashboard', component: TutorDashboardComponent },
    ],
  },
  { path: '', component: FacadeComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component:AdminPortalComponent,
  pathMatch:'full',
    children:[
      { path: 'categories',component:CategoriesComponent},
      { path: 'analytics',component:AnalyticsComponent}
    ]
  },
];
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    all the components and pipes..
  ],
  imports: [
    ... ,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
  ],
  entryComponents: [WelcomeComponent],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Now if I go to `home/tutor-dashboard` on a click of button.. it works.
But when I try to refresh it gives me this error:
[image]

And when I try to open `admin/categories` it doesn't show up.. giving the error:

[image]

I made sure that I have router outlet in every parent component.
And when I put

```
RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, useHash: 'true')
```

all works.. but I don't wanna use Hash.

Please help me with the problem.

I studied about `.htaccess` file that rewrites the url but I think that's for post production.. here it is even not working on local server.

found base href in my index html and i am using angular 9

```
<base href="./" />
```

Comment: I may not have noticed on production environments but I don't think you see the hash on those production URLs. Maybe build and deploy it to check that. Second I don't think hashing is on the "avoid" list of SEO of google.

Comment: could you please tell which version of angular are you using, and search for `baseHref` or `base-href` in your files, and paste here all the corresponding findings